# Algorithm for 2D line segment morphing

Tags: iphone, algorithm, math, geometry

Creating a puzzle game where I want the shapes to morph based on user input. A user clicks on a vertex and drags the point changing the shape. For example if a user clicks on A and drags downward (shortening segment AG), point B would would down an equal amount (shortening BC), point F would move to the left shortening both AF and FG, finally point E would also shift to the left to stay in line with point F.

There is an array of line segments, each line segment is itself an array that contains the two end points. When shifting I have a loop search for all the equal points. None of this is set in stone willing to make any changes needed to get this to work.

I've been working on this for two days and am completely stumped.

```
                A
   B-------------\
    |           | \
    |           |  \
    |           |   \
    |           |    \
   C------------------\F
    |           G     |
    |                 |
    |                 |
   D-------------------E
```

Comment: This problem is underconstrained. That means there are may ways to change that figure and keep all of the angles the same. For instance, you could lengthen B, E and G by ten miles. Tell us what you're trying to do. (And label the vertices, not the segments.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simultaneous equations, innit?

I'm assuming that each line is supposed to retain its slope. Then your figure satisfies these equations (or nearly these equations, I'm not 100% sure about the slope of the AF line):

> B.x = C.x = D.x
>
> B.y = A.y
>
> C.y = G.y = F.y
>
> D.y = E.y
>
> A.x = G.x
>
> F.x = E.x
>
> (A.y - F.y) = 2(F.x - A.x)

When the player is dragging A, then A.y and A.x are effectively constant, so you have eleven equations and twelve unknowns. (There's some under-constraining, as Beta points out, because the three equations B.x = C.x = D.x don't relate to any of the others, and neither does D.y = E.y.)

What you probably want is the solution that changes the fewest of your variables. I don't know how to do that. But since this is a game, it probably doesn't matter if occasionally you don't get *quite* the minimum set of changes. So maybe a greedy algorithm would work, like this:

- Let S be the set of variable that we keep constant. Initialise it to the empty set.
- For each variable V, if the set of equations can be solved keeping the variables in S ∪ {V} contant, add V to S.
- The last solution you found is the one you use.

Comment: This should work. One question when you say Ay & Ax are effectively constant what do you mean? Since they are the ones changing?

Comment: They have to follow the player's finger, so you have no choice about where they go.

Comment: This is better than my unification stuff - and fits with the simplex stuff (if you go that far) as there are matrixy methods for simultaneous equations (Gaussian elimination?) - though you may just have a manually solved form for each level.

Comment: Thx. I was misunderstanding 'constant'. Was thinking of it in mathematical terms

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was linear programming with the simplex algorithm, but I think this is either wrong or at least incomplete. Basically, most if not all of your rules are linear this-equals-that rules, where linear programming deals with this-is-less-than-that (or <= or whatever) rules.

The fix may be unification. That is, express your rules WRT as few variables as possible. Where you have a rule f(a) = g(b), you can effectively eliminate b by defining b=g'(f(a)) and substituting everywhere else you find the b. Since actually substituting is inefficient, you can just make a note of the relationship between a and b.

With minor complications, the basic approach is union-find. In the exact-equality case, you would eliminate b by adding a link from b to a. When 'finding' b, you then identify a (or whatever it has been linked to) instead. So at any time, you can efficiently translate any rule to a form that uses only non-eliminated variables. The complication in this case - you need to keep a running track of the g'(f(a)) style stuff as you follow the links. As this is all linear, it shouldn't be that big a problem, but not trivial either.

You might need to be able to backtrack the unification - make a note of the links you set on a stack, so you can null them again in the correct order as you unwind the stack.

I'm not sure if you have any relative conditions at all (less than or whatever), but if so, once you've eliminated as many variables as possible, you'll still need some linear programming. If you have two remaining variables, this is conceptually simple. For each linear condition on those two variables, draw a line on a 2D graph such that one side of the line represents the valid region. The conditions are traditionally "normalised" so the valid side always includes the origin. Based on crossing points, the line-segments nearest the origin form a convex polygon. An optimal solution is on one of the corners, and is assessed using a linear scoring rule (the thing you're optimising) which would in your case be defined to give the "best" shape where there's some ambiguity or some conflict of priorities in your rules - e.g. you can't push a point all the way through a line, so things get blocked at certain points.

If you have more than two variables remaining, you need a multi-dimensional equivalent of a convex polygon - and that is called a simplex. Practical implementation of the simplex algorithm involves matrices.

This is already oversimplified to the point that it's probably wrong in some of the details, and it's about as far as I can explain. IIRC you can get good descriptions of these component techniques in Sedgewick, though Wikipedia may be just as good these days.

Simplex solvers are sometimes used for Window layouts - I think wxWidgets uses one for resizing the controls in a window, for example. Unification is a defining feature of logic programming (Prolog etc), but the underlying union-find principles are simple enough. The key trick is figuring out how to translate a 2D figure into a set of rules expressing how it will change, and understanding how to represent and manipulate those rules, particularly in matrix form.

Comment: Cool, thx. I'll take a look into everything you said. What does WRT stand for?

Comment: @Help - With Respect To. Sorry - addicted to abbreviations.

Comment: LOL... i thought it was a math term I had never heard of. thx again

Answer (score 0):

How about this...does your puzzle only have triangles, rectangles and squares? In that case, you may develop a method to deal with each shape depending on which vertex is moved and which shapes are affected by that vertex's move...In your example, moving vertex A will impact square ABCG and triangle AGF. So, when A moves, vertex C remains unaffected...you only need to "reposition" B and G. Unless I understand your example wrong, I dont see how moving A will affect F, though. HTH.